# Adjectives for silent/loud and light/heavy weaponry

Tags: single-word-requests

I am designing a simple video game set in a [steampunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk) world where player will be able to get weapons in four different variations:

- silent and light
- loud and light
- silent and heavy
- loud and heavy

I am trying to come up with some adjective prefixes or suffixes to distinguish between them. Selection of weapon types is going to be quite wast, ranging from knives and bows to assault rifles and rocket launchers, so I would love to have adjectives usable with any kind of weapon. For now I have these ideas:

- silent and light - *sneaky*, ...
- loud and light   - *agile*, *nimble*
- silent and heavy - ...
- loud and heavy   - *brute*, ...

I would highly appreciate any help and suggestions, especially for silent and heavy variation. Of course it is desirable for words to "go together" and not look like being out of theme.

P. S. Sorry for my English, I am not a native speaker and am trying my best.

Comment: Silent makes it sneaky but what about light? Light makes it agile, but what about loud? Loud and heavy do make it brute.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and our format is very ill-suited to generating lists of suggestions. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance. I would also have a look at the additional guidance for [tag:single-word-requests].

Comment: My suggestion would be to use animal names as metaphors.  For instance: **1. Silent and light** Cobra (or Black Mamba or Viper or Scorpion)  **2. Loud and light** Wolverine (or Hyena or Wolf) **3. Silent and heavy** Panther (or Lion or Shark or Crocodile) **4. Loud and heavy** Bear (or Rhino or Hippo or Elephant)

Answer (score 1):

In order: Stealthy / Advancing / Raiding / Storming.  Or what about non-adjective, metaphor-based categories, like Special Ops / Combat / Tactical / Siege?